# 3 different ways to integrate $ \ln(\sqrt{x})$ and outcomes $3$ different answers.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

### Method 1

$\int \frac {\ln\sqrt{x}}x$

Let $u = x^{1/2}$ , so $du = \frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}dx$

$2\int \frac {\ln{u}}u$

= $\frac{ln{(u)}^2}3$ = $\frac{ln(\sqrt{x})^2}3$

### Method 2

$\int \frac {\ln\sqrt{x}}x$

$\frac12\int\frac{ln{(x)}}x$ = $(ln{(x)})^2-\int\frac{\ln(x)}x$

$\frac32\int\frac{ln{(x)}}x$ 
 = $(ln{(x)})^2$

$\int\frac{ln{(x)}}x$ = $\frac{2(ln{(x)})^2}3$

### Method 3

$\int \frac {\ln\sqrt{x}}x$

Let $u = \ln{(\sqrt{x})}$, so $du = \frac1{\sqrt{x}}\times\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}dx$ = $\frac1{2x}dx$

$2\int u du = u^{2}$

= $(\ln{\sqrt{x}})^2$

How's that possible?
Different methods give me  $3$ different answers? Which one of these is the correct answer?

Comment: (ln(x)^2)/4 + C doesn't seem like the correct answer.
If you take the derivative of that you get ln(sqrt(x))/4x, not ln(sqrt(x))/x

Answer (score 2):

Apparently none of them, since if you take $u = \ln x$ then $du = \frac{1}{x} dx$, then

$$\frac{1}{2}\int u \ du = \frac{u^2}{4} + C = \color{#f05}{\frac{\ln^2 x}{4}} + C$$

**Note:** To check your answer compute the derivative of each one.

Comment: (ln(x)^2)/4 + C doesn't seem like the correct answer. If you take the derivative of that you get ln(sqrt(x))/4x, not ln(sqrt(x))/x

Comment: Try it again. You must be doing something wrong. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+%28ln%5E2+x%29%2F%284%29).

Comment: Remember that $\ln \sqrt {x} = \frac{1}{2} \ln x$.

Comment: Just say in case you didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

One has $$\int\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\ln\left(x\right)d\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{2}.$$

When you change your variable $u\mapsto f\left(x\right)$, you must be able to express $x\mapsto f^{-1}\left(u\right)$.
Your first calculus is wrong because of the factor $\frac{1}{3}$.
In your second one, you did and integration by part, but forgot the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.
Finally, in the last calculus, you must express $x$ in term of $u$ which may involve some exponential terms maybe...

Comment: (ln(x)^2)/4 + C doesn't seem like the correct answer. If you take the derivative of that you get ln(sqrt(x))/4x, not ln(sqrt(x))/x

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\times2\ln\left(x\right)\times\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\sqrt{x}\right).$$ You forgot the factor $2$ which comes from ^2.

Comment: Then isn't (ln(sqrt(x)))^2 correct as well? Try taking its derivative

Comment: $$ \left(\ln\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)^{2}=\left(0.5\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{2}=0.25\left(\ln\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)^{2}
  $$ is the answer we gave with Aaron Maroja, no problem!